# Magento Invoice emails sending twice

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice

For some reason when an order is processed magento automatically sends 2 Invoice emails as well as the order confirmations email.

I have 2 questions.

1. Should magento send an invoice email automatically ( I am using a payment gateway that authorises and captures payment so I believe the invoice is generated at the time of sale.)
2. How do I find out what is sending the emails i.e. is it magento, my payment gateway, another extension???? Is there a way to trace this?

Current work around is I have the invoice email disabled and it stops the 2 invocie emails being sent.

Cheers

Comment: In that case any observer playing the role , do you have any custom observer

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to find out. But how do I know if there is a custom observer?